# plotting values on graph using achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine, android-graphview

How i cant set the y axis values which has limits from 200 to 800 with interval of 10.
which parameters need to set for this. and i need dates on the x axis with interval of 1 day. how can i draw this kind of chart using achartengine library

i have used following functions for setting renderer

```
 renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
 renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
 renderer.setYAxisMin(200);
 renderer.setYAxisMax(800);
 renderer.setYLabels(5);
 renderer.setXLabels(5);
```

Comment: use timeseries for dates .

Comment: "2014-02-17"      "2014-02-23"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add custom axis labels like this:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```